# PHP - Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0'

Tags: php

This has got to be one of the strangest errors I have error come across jsut because the exact same code on two other systems work fine.

Let me explain my set up and how and where it works. First of all I am using zend framework and the error is thrown in the Zend/View/Abstract class on line 300.

Windows system running PHP 5.3.3 - Works Fine Here.
Linux Centos 5.5 system running PHP 5.3.3 - Works Fine here.
Linux Centos 5.5 system running PHP 5.3.6 - This system gives me the fatal error.

PHP -  Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0'

Looking at the setup I first thought that this had to be a bug in PHP but I am not so sure. I first had PHP 5.3.5 installed and upgraded to 5.3.6 but that didnt help.

The code throwing the error should work also so I am completely confused as to why I am getting the error on this system and not the other two.

Code that is throwing the error is :

```
$this->$key = $val;
```

Located in the following method:

```
public function __set($key, $val)
{
        if ('_' != substr($key, 0, 1)) {
            $this->$key = $val;
            return;
        }

        require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
        $e = new Zend_View_Exception('Setting private or protected class members is not allowed');
        $e->setView($this);
        throw $e;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I did some further debugging and it isn't one of my variables causing the error. I found that when the $key variable was set to Zend_View_useViewStream the fatal error is thrown, so I vardumped it before and after it was string trimmed.

```
KEY string(25) "Zend_View_useViewStream" 
TRIMMED string(24) "Zend_View_useViewStream"
```

As you can see the string lenght is 1 character longer when the variable is not trimmed but they seem identical to me?? I guess the nul-byte [ "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte. ] is being stripped with trim but why is it being added on this system and not the others?

Comment: How are you setting a value ?

Comment: What happens when you try to print_r($key) before using it as property name? Apparently, for some reason it starts with \0.

Answer (score 5):

`__set()` is a [Magic Method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) that's called when you try and set a property that doesn't exist. If it's throwing an error in `Zend_View_Abstract` then one of your views is trying to set an instance property that doesn't exist, and the instance property begins with a null character.

```
$this->$property = $value;
```

You could try and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the property

```
$property = trim($property);
$this->$property = $value;
```

I have a feeling that something is attempting to modify `$this` erroneously. Can you track down the code in your view?

Comment: Ok if i trim the $key variable it works but this is not the best solution because I am modifying code in the zend framework library.I am still clueless as to why it works on the two other systems and this one not.

Comment: @Ilan Well, where is `$key` coming from? You should probably examine the stack trace from the error to figure out which bit of your code is causing this to be called.

Comment: I did some further debugging and it isn't one of my variables causing the error. I found that when the $key variable was set to Zend_View_useViewStream the fatal error is thrown, so I vardumped it before and after it was string trimmed.

KEY     string(25) "Zend_View_useViewStream"
TRIMMED string(24) "Zend_View_useViewStream"  As you can see the string lenght is 1 character longer when the variable is not trimmed but they seem identical to me??

Comment: The null character `\0` is a zero width character. It doesn't look like anything! [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Comment: Sometimes necessary to trim twice: `trim(trim($key))`

Comment: omg i'm twelve years late

Answer (score 4):

I would have said it's a locale-thing again. But appearantly this has been cemented in current PHP versions:

```
    if (Z_STRVAL_P(member)[0] == '\0') {
            if (!silent) {
                    if (Z_STRLEN_P(member) == 0) {
                            zend_error(E_ERROR, "Cannot access empty property");
                    } else {
                            zend_error(E_ERROR, "Cannot access property started with '\\0'");
                    }
            }
            return NULL;
```

<s>So we can conclue this was introduced somewhen around PHP 5.3.3 to 5.3.6. (My version is 5.3.2, same effect, but probably a backported patch).</s> Cannot find anything what indicates the reason in the changelog.

Anyway, you cannot use binary property names then if you don't ensure they don't start with NUL.

--

The change occured between PHP 5.0.0 and PHP 5.1.0 already:

- http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/tags/php_5_0_0/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c
- http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/tags/php_5_1_0/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c

And I'm suspecting this is the reason:

```
if (prop_info_name[0] == '\0' && prop_info_name[1] != '*' && !(property_info->flags & ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE)) {
    /* we we're looking for a private prop but found a non private one of the same name */
    return FAILURE;
}
```

I haven't looked this through, but from that snippet I assume the `\0` byte was used for something different originally and got then forbidden later on ..

Comment: When I remember it correctly `\0` was a prefix to mark a property as private in the older version of PHP. There was also a hack to access private properties using this prefix manually. But since the Reflection Class is available this hack is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i presume that `$key` is a string beginning with `"\0"`.

Comment: @RobertPitt: I don't think so, this might very well be the solution. It is just not stated as one.

Comment: @soulmerge, he specified that it was working on several operation systems but `Centos` was causing the problem, which ** obviously** indicates an environment

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. I was trying to access an object that is not fully initialized because of the LazyLoading. Make sure that the object is initialized before accessing it. In my case, I had to load the object from my DB and fully initialized it.